# Using NextJS to do SSR with Class Components and getInitialProps, render method has undefined data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am fairly new to JavaScript/React/NextJS.  I have written a React app and I am now trying to convert it so that all of it renders on the server.

I went through the tutorials on https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started and then i tried to apply that knowledge to my app.

I have the following requirements in my app

- I have a master detail scenario. The main page renders a list of articles, clicking on one of those articles takes the user to articles details.
- I want to have clean urls, such as "/article/123" and not "article?id=123".
- I am using a 3rd party library to get the data from the server, therefore I have to use promises to get the data
- I need to use Class Components not functional components (for other reasons can not move to functional components).
- I want all the rendering to occur on the server not the client

I am unclear how in "getInitialProps" i would call my async method in my 3rd party library and return the data. Nothing i try is working and googling hasn't helped.

My project structure is

```
- components
     |- header.js
     |- footer.js
     |- layout.js
- pages
     |- index.js
     |- article
          |- [id].js
- scripts
     |- utils.js
```

index.js just renders 2 links for 2 articles

```
export default function Index() {
     return (
        <div>
            <Link href="/article/[id]" as={`/article/1`}>
                <a>Article 1</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/article/[id]" as={`/article/2`}>
                <a>Article 2</a>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

utils.js has a util method to call the 3rd party library method

```
export function getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId) { 
    return thirdPartyLib.getMyData({
        "articleId" : articleId,
    }).then(function (item) {  
        return item;
   });
 }
```

article/[id].js has

```
 function getData(articleId){
     console.log("getData")
     getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
        .then((item) => {
            console.log("got data")
            return {
                item: item
            }
        });
 } 

 class ArticleDetails extends React.Component {

     static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
         const data = await getData(articleId);
         // I also tried the following
         // const data = getData(articleId);

         return{
             data : data 
         }
     }

     render() {
         console.log("IN RENDER")
         console.log("this.props.data") // THIS IS UNDEFINED
         // my HTML
     }
  }
```

**Problem** :

console logging shows that the data is always undefined in render(). I can see my logging from getting the data and data is obtained, but these render after my render logging, so render is not refreshed once the data is obtained.

**Different attempt 1**

I tried having "getData" inside my component definition (as apposed to outside it) but this always fails as it says the "getData" is not a function.

```
 class ArticleDetails extends React.Component {

     static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
         const data = await getData(articleId); // FAILS AS SAYS getData is not a function

         return{
             data : data 
         }
     }

     getData(articleId){
         console.log("getData")
         getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
            .then((item) => {
                return {
                    item: item
                }
            });
     } 

     render() {
         console.log("IN RENDER")
         console.log(this.props.data) // THIS IS UNDEFINED
         // my HTML
     }
  }
```

**Different attempt 2**

I tried having the logic in "getData" directly in "getInitialProps" but that also doesn't work as it says getInitialProps must return an object.

```
 class ArticleDetails extends React.Component {

     static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
          getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
            .then((item) => {
                return {
                    data: data
                }
          });
     }

     render() {
         console.log("IN RENDER")
         console.log(this.props.data) // THIS IS UNDEFINED
         // my HTML
     }
  }
```

**Working version - but not SSR**

The only way i can get this to work is to write it like a class component in a React App. But I believe "componentDidMount" is not called on the server, its called in the Client. So this defeats my attempt of getting everything to render in the server.

```
class ArticleDetails  extends React.Component {

    state = {
        item: null,


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }


    getData(articleId){
         console.log("getData")
         getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
            .then((item) => {
                self.setState({                
                    item: item
                }
            });
    } 

    render() {
         console.log("IN RENDER")
         console.log(this.state.item) // THIS HAS A VALUE
         // my HTML
    }    

}
```

**SOLUTION as provided by Steve Holgado**

The problem was that my "getData" method was not returning the promise as Steve said.

However my "getData" method was a little more complex than I put in this post originally which was why when I first tried Steve's solution it did not work.

My getData is nesting two promises. If i put the return on BOTH promises it works perfectly.

```
function getData(articleId){
     return getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
        .then((item) => {

             return getSecondBitOfDataFromThirdPartyLib(item)
                .then((extraInfo) => {
                    return {
                        item: item,
                        extraInfo : extraInfo
                    }
                });

            return {
                item: item
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from `getData` in `article/[id].js`:

```
function getData(articleId){
  // return promise here
  return getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)
    .then((item) => {
      return {
        item: item
      }
    });
}
```

...otherwise `undefined` is returned implicitly.

Also, where are you getting `articleId` from?

Is it supposed to come from the url?

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  const articleId = ctx.query.id;
  const data = await getData(articleId);

  return {
    data: data 
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i am getting the articleId from the URL just like you have put in your example. Sorry i missed this out.
Unfortunately changing the code as you suggested i am still getting "undefined" in my render method

Comment: Do you see the correct data if you console log it in the `.then` after `getDataFromThirdPartyLib(articleId)`?

Comment: yes i get the data.
The only wonder i have is that this file is in "pages/p/[id].js". A lot of places say that "getInitialProps" only works for pages.  Does this include these subpages also?  I presume so seeing as my getData is being called

Comment: Yes, that should still work. Do you have a public git repo?

Comment: No i do not have a public git repos. But i have found the issue with your help.  My getData method is actually chaining promises. I only put the "return" on the first one after i read your comment. When i put return on both i get the right data. I have updated my question as its easier to see the solution.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the correct answer. Thank you so very much steve-holgado